# W3C validator showing error

Tags: perl, w3c-validation

After enter any URL when I click check in order to validate it shows.

```
Can't locate SGML/Parser/OpenSP.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib .) at C:/xampp/htdocs/validator/httpd/cgi-bin/check line 64.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/xampp/htdocs/validator/httpd/cgi-bin/check line 64.
```

Any Idea why its happening?

Comment: You don't have the sgml parser module installed?

Comment: Because you don't have [SGML::Parser::OpenSP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SGML::Parser::OpenSP) installed?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP but when I visit [SGML-Parser-OpenSP](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/SGML-Parser-OpenSP/) it shows SGML-Parser-OpenSP is unavailable in PPM, because there aren't any builds for it in the package repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not installed [OpenSP](http://search.cpan.org/~bjoern/SGML-Parser-OpenSP-0.994/lib/SGML/Parser/OpenSP.pm). You will need to install it first. I think you are working with `WebService::Validator::HTML::W3C`. If that is the case and you are about to validate multiple files then you should get a local copy of the W3C validator. The procedure to install the local validator is well explained in [W3C installation document](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html).

Comment: Yes I'm trying to install the W3C validator locally, everything is working but at the [installation guide] (http://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html#needed-programs) for installing the OpenSP perl module named **SGML-Parser-OpenSP**.
But It showed that  SGML-Parser-OpenSP is unavailable in PPM, because there aren't any builds for it in the package repositories.

Comment: I just installed it 3 days ago, it worked fine for me. Download OpenSP from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openjade/. Note that the validator will not work with any version of OpenSP earlier than 1.5.2. Or you may try running `cpan SGML::Parser::OpenSP`.

Comment: Yes, try it. Did you trying installing from cpan too? Both methods should work.